# Table doesn't have a primary key when adding a new row to datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have a datatable in windows form and I want to add a new row to the table. I always receive the error

> Table doesn't have a primary key.

The question is that I don't want a primary key at all. It may have duplicated "ID" in the table.
My code:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
dt.Columns.Add("EntryDE", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Descr", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    if (check.Value != null)
    {
        if ((bool)check.Value)
        {
            //this row has a checkBox set to true (tick is added)
            //add this row to dataTable ...
            DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["EntryDE"] = myRow["ID"].ToString();        
            dr["Descr"] = myRow["EntryName"];               
            dr["Id"] = Id;    
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: where is the dr["Id"] = `Id` come from in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error isn't coming from the DataTable because this works:

```
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("EntryDE", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Descr", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["EntryDE"] = "abc";
            dr["Descr"] = "xyz";
            dr["Id"] = 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
```

You've got some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do want a primary key, as without it you'll be unable to update or delete rows later on.

If the ID field is going to contain duplicates, then you should add another column, call it primary_key or whatever you like, and use that column as PK.